# "No such file or directory" with "brew doctor" command

Tags: macos, homebrew

I've got `No such file or directory` with `brew doctor` command.

Here is my config:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
HEAD: 526ef67d3ce9229fd6cb91963e2afce0d32fb7ae
Last commit: 55 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.10.3-x86_64
Xcode: 6.3.2
CLT: 6.3.2.0.1.1431401888
Clang: 6.1 build 602
X11: 2.7.7 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 2.0.0-p481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /usr/local/bin/ruby => /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_31
```

And here is the output for `brew doctor -d`:

```
...
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Library/Taps/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/phpmyadmin.rb
Error: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/find.rb:40:in `block in find'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/find.rb:40:in `collect!'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/find.rb:40:in `find'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb:543:in `find'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:918:in `__check_linked_brew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:931:in `block in check_for_linked_keg_only_brews'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:930:in `select'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:930:in `check_for_linked_keg_only_brews'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1236:in `block in doctor'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1234:in `each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1234:in `doctor'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:149:in `<main>'
```

All is fine with `brew update`.
I made a `git pull origin master` in `/usr/local/Library` folder.

If you have any idea...

Comment: As `brew` is only a shell script, how about trying `sh -xv /usr/local/bin/brew doctor`

Comment: Same thing than before: `Error: No such file or directory`

Comment: I uninstalled brew and reinstalled it. All is fine now ...

Comment: Excellent! Well done.